# Savon fault response in SOAP Reques: "The message with Action 'x' cannot be processed at the receiver..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, savon

I'm using Savon for a Web Service Client implementation.

However, I get this message:

> (a:ActionNotSupported) The message
>   with Action 'SearchCars' cannot be
>   processed at the receiver, due to a
>   ContractFilter mismatch at the
>   EndpointDispatcher. This may be
>   because of either a contract mismatch
>   (mismatched Actions between sender and
>   receiver) or a binding/security
>   mismatch between the sender and the
>   receiver.  Check that sender and
>   receiver have the same contract and
>   the same binding (including security
>   requirements, e.g. Message, Transport,
>   None).

after sending my soap request.

I read it had something to do with a httpBinding or something.

Any ideas?

Comment: Might be worth checking to make sure you're binding to httpclient and not Net/HTTP.  This might also help: [Ruby HTTP Clients](https://spreadsheets0.google.com/pub?hl=en&hl=en&key=0AiZsKd8d4hSJdHFFbjR5aWNjWjlzWlhiNGxQejdBWWc&output=html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a working client another mechanism (eg curl)?

What I find useful is to see look at the differences between the http requests, using something like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

And/or [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) is a handy tool for inspecting web services and trying them out.  Have you tried connecting with that?

HTH, Chris